# ASP.NET MVC generic service interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a web application with a few controllers mainly performing CRUD operations. These are created using a scaffolding template which creates almost everything with a few clicks.
However, for other modules with heavier business logic (e.g. something as 'simple' as master-details views), I see that my controllers get polluted with code which doesn't seem to belong there but in a service.
So, what I want to do is to write a service layer which, at least, serves as a proxy to the repository related operations (GetAll, GetById, Update, etc...), so I can have a templated controller which includes this service for the appropriate entity and will be nearly always the same.

The problem I see is that ClientService and OrderService share a part of the interface. So I thought I could group that functionality into an IService interface and then the bussiness logic IClientService and IOrderService interface would inherit that base interface. So my controllers would have a dependency on the I[EntityName]Service.

I read that interface inheritance many times is a sign of design flaw, but I don't want to expose the underlying repository interface which is my DbContext (I know it is in fact a UoW).

Another option is to expose the IService interface through a property in IClientInterface.

Comment: I wouldn't inherit IClientService and IOrderService from IService. I would place common interface in ICommonService and then I would implement interfaces ICommonService and IClientService in ClientService class and ICommonService and IOrderService.in OrderService class. Nothing bad here.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with a base `IService` interface. Just have `IOrderService` and `IClientService`. If they both have similar named methods, so what. Keep things simple for yourself - whatever classes implement those interfaces are not linked to each other anyway, so don't bother with a base interface.

Comment: But then what kind of dependency would I have in my controllers in order to have access to both interfaces? If my ClientController has a IClientService, then I won't have access to IService methods.